# Advanced Filter Copies in one Case but Fails in the Other?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have an advance filter with criteria as follows:

```
Range(ClientRange).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,
CriteriaRange:=Range(ClntName), CopyToRange:=Range("AA2"), unique:=True
```

and it works just fine. It copies the title and the data.
But in the next case I have no criteria as follows:

```
Range("F2").Select
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
SiteRange = "F2:" & "F" & Lastrow
Range(SiteRange).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=Range("AB2"), Unique:=True
Range("AB2").Select
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
SiteData = "AB2:" & "AB" & Lastrow
```

It only copies the title, which comes from F2, and puts it on AB2. If I check `SiteRange` it shows a `Range(F2:F518`), so there is data there to copy.
On the other hand if you check `SiteData` it only shows a `Range(AB2:AB2)`
I must be missing something; can anyone help figure it out?

I have cut down the program to show the Advanced filters only and to illustrate how they seem to work selectively. I know it is my programming but hopefully it will make it easier to see the problem. Code follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Scheduling()
 Dim NewSheet As Worksheet, NameSheet As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
 Dim cell As Object
 Dim SheetRange As String
 Dim ClientRange As String
 Dim ClntCrit As String
 Dim ClntName As String
 Dim ClientCcs As String
 Dim SiteRange As String
 Dim StaffRange As String
 Dim CodeRange As String
 Dim Lastrow As Long

 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Schedules").Activate
 Set NameSheet = Sheets("Schedules")

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Range("$BE$2").Select
   Selection.Value = "Client Name"
   Range("$BE$3").Select
   Selection.Value = "*-ccs*"
   Range("$BF$2").Select
   Selection.Value = "Client Name"
   Range("$BF$3").Select
   Selection.Value = "<>*-ccs*"
   Range("$BG$2").Select
   Selection.Value = "Client Name"
   Range("B2").Select
   Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
   ClientRange = "B2:" & "B" & Lastrow
   Range("F2").Select
   Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
   SiteRange = "F2:" & "F" & Lastrow
   Range("G2").Select
   Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
   StaffRange = "G2:" & "G" & Lastrow
   Range("H2").Select
   Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
   CodeRange = "H2:" & "H" & Lastrow
   Range("$BF$2").Select
   ClntName = "$BF$2:$BF$3"
   Range("$BE$2").Select
   ClntCrit = "$BE$2:$BE$3"
   Range(ClientRange).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,
   CriteriaRange:=Range(ClntCrit), CopyToRange:=Range("$BG$2"),
   unique:=True
   Range(ClientRange).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,
   CriteriaRange:=Range(ClntName), CopyToRange:=Range("AA2"),
   unique:=True
   Range(SiteRange).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,
   CopyToRange:=Range("AB2"), unique:=True
   Range(StaffRange).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, 
   CopyToRange:=Range("AC2"), unique:=True
   Range(CodeRange).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,
   CopyToRange:=Range("AD2"), unique:=True
 End Sub
```

The first two Advanced filter with criteria work just fine. The next three Advanced filters return the Titles only.

Hopefully someone will see where the conflict is in this arrangement since it should work.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. That same code works at my end.

Comment: Thanks @L42 ... Can something later in the program affect this outcome?

Comment: Yeah probably. Try isolating it with the rest of the code first and run it as a separate routine if it still behaves as you've describe. If not, then the rest of your code might be affecting it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify the 'SHEET reference' for the 'Range'

Comment: Thanks @Arya ... I will give your suggestion a try since I am not having any luck solving this issue as of yet.

Comment: No Luck ... I tried ThisWorkBook.WorkSheets(1).Range and it did not change the outcome .. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution. Later today I will run it on the complete program but for now this works:

I moved the Advanced Filters without Criteria above the Advanced Filters with Criteria, in other words the Advanced Filters without Criteria ran first and the result was:

All of the Advanced Filters copied the appropriate ranges to there respective ranges without any problems.

I will have to read up on these Advanced Filters and no doubt I will find that one has to run them in a specific order?